# How do I delete a customer attribute?

Tags: database, customer, customer-attribute, magento2.2.3

After a data migration, everything works besides my admin customer page. When I click I get an exception error. When contacting the author of the data migration tool he said I need to delete the `is_contact` attribute. I went into the database and deleted it. Went ahead and cleared the cache and ran setup upgrade and the attribute came back in the database. Thought I made a mistake, deleted again, and it came back again. How do I delete it? I am on `Magento 2.2.3 EE`.

**Edit:** Removed in the EAV Attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

And you are sure that you deleted the attribute from `InstallData.php` and `UpgradeData.php`. Look for the project by the attribute code.

I hope that my answer will bring you closer to a solution.

Comment: I looked for both of those files in my IDE and I have a ton of them. Any idea how to find it? When I search for is_contact in the ide nothing shows up.

Comment: do you remove the `eav_attribute` from the table?

Comment: Yes. That is why I can't figure out why it comes back. I should have specified that in the original post.